# How to run my html file with apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Maybe it is not a right channel to ask this question but I donot know where to ask.

I want to know how to run html file with apache on my ubuntu. I have written program with javascript and a html file and I want to run it via apache. I could not find htdocs folder in to copy my files there beside that I do not have permission to do that in ubuntu. My apache is installed in /usr/share/apache2.
When I write `http://localhost` it says:

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

but I do not know where to add the contents.

any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default folder that it serves the HTML files from is `/var/www`.

For example, `/var/www/test.html` would be `http://localhost/test.html`.

Comment: `/var/www` is the default directory that Apache serves from when running on Ubuntu- which is what they asked and what they've tagged the question as.

Comment: So everytime that I want to run my application I should go to this folder? is there any way to run my program easily? thanks

Comment: That's the default one that it will use, and that's just where you need to save the files on the file system. To run it you just need to use your browser at `http://localhost/` or the web address under that. You can change where it Apache looks for HTML files by modifying the configuration: http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-apache-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

In my case where I have installed and running the Apache 2 and if I type `localhost/` into the browser it opens the Apache 2 Ubuntu default Page.

Now what I did was:
Suppose your HTML webpage Demo.html is located in the Website directory then copy the HTML page using one of the commands:

```
:~$ cp ~/Website/Demo.html /var/www/html
```

If this command does not work then try with the following command:

```
:~$ sudo cp ~/Website/Demo.html /var/www/html
```

And then open your browser and type this the browser search bar:
localhost/Demo.html

It will open the copied Demo.html.

Also if you want to access this hosted webpage from the outside of the machine where Apache 2 is running then use it's external IP address instead of localhost as follows:

```
ExternalIP/Demo.html
```